# How to remove one polyline of several with jquery.ui.map?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I have two polylines on the map:

1. Polyline 1 as `route`
2. Polyline 2 as `other`

I want to clear only one. How can I do that?

I have tried with:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'overlays > Polyline').route
```

But it does not work.

```js
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 
                'Polyline', {
                 tags:'other',
          property: 'tags',
     path: other_positions,
   strokeColor: '#ff0000',
   strokeOpacity: 1.0,
   strokeWeight: 2
  });
 
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 
                'Polyline', {
   tags:'route',
          property: 'tags',
   path: array_positions,
   strokeColor: '#0000ff',
   strokeOpacity: 1.0,
   strokeWeight: 2
  });
```

When clicking a button, I want only this polyline (route) to be cleared while it clears both

Comment: Can you post in your code sample?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just have the code portion that has the `path =>array_positions`

```js
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Polyline', { tags:'route', 
property: 'tags', path: array_positions, 
strokeColor: '#0000ff', strokeOpacity: 1.0, strokeWeight: 2 });
```

Getting rid of the Poly line that displays the other positions.